# Fire an action only if state has changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

my state is a rather large object, but for simplicity just pretend its something like this:

```
{
    otherStuff: {},
    currUser: {
      name: 'John',
      age: 20,
      location: 'NY'
    }
}
```

I have a `saveUser(user)` action I want to do ONLY if any of the information inside `currUser` has changed since the last time `saveUser` had been done. What is the best way to do this? Should I save the state at that point and then compare later on? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Add hash-code to the object and compare hash-codes before update

Comment: are you using redux?

Comment: yes im using redux

Answer (score 0):

follow this (assuming you are using redux)

1) do mapStateToProps of currUser in any react component (say, 'Login')

2) in Login class, under componentWillReceiveProps, compare this.props with nextProps and see if your currUser object is changing

3) if yes, trigger the saveUser action.

In case of you request as per comment below:

Its fairly simple, In submit handler, t

1) import action to the desired form component

2) Do bindActionCreators inside mapstatetoprops, hope you using Redux / store state

3) use this.props.YourAction inside submit handler.

Does this work for u?

Comment: the issue is I need to fire the action inside a form submit handler, so I can't move it to `componentWillReceiveProps` (I only want it to run if its in response to a form and only if form data has changed basically).